# Does this even make any sense?

Tags: american-english, british-english, spoken-english

> The killer who preys.

I saw this on a  picture of a cheetah. 
Shouldn't "preys" be "prays"?
Is the grammar right?

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Prey and pray](https://writingexplained.org/pray-vs-prey-difference) are different words. In your context prey is the correct word.

Answer (score 2):

Cheetahs are animals who prey. The grammar is absolutely right.

Comment: Was typo. I edited.